# C#, how to save frequency of elements from one array in another, two-dimensional array?

Tags: c#, arrays

So here's my problematic code. When I try to pass an array with N arguments, let's say {2,1,2,2,5} in result I want to get two-dimensional secArray[element,frequency of the element]. The problem is I get more than that and in this particular case I get an array like this:
23
11
22
21
52

```
        Console.WriteLine("Enter number of elements: ");
        int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int[] array = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("Array[{0}]: ", i);
            array[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }

        //problematic code begins
        int[,] secArray = new int[n,2];

        for(int i = 0;i<n;i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j<n;j++)
            {

                if(array[i] == secArray[j,0])
                {
                    secArray[j, 1] += 1;
                }

                else
                {
                    secArray[i, 0] = array[i];
                    secArray[i, 1] = 1;
                }
            }
        }
        //problematic code ends
        //printing - works good
        Console.WriteLine("How many same elements?");
        for (int row = 0; row < secArray.GetLength(0); row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < secArray.GetLength(1); col++)
            {
                Console.Write(secArray[row, col]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
```

If anyone has a clue how to fix this I'll be really grateful. It frustrates me that I don't know where the actual problem lies.

Comment: Wouldnt a Dictionary be a better datatype to hold this information?  The key is the element, and the frequency is the value

Comment: @maccettura You're probably right, but it was important to me to solve this in an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem concerns the very first statement.

```
int[,] secArray = new int[n,2];
```

You don't know how many unique elements you have in your array until you traverse it. You can't use n, because n is the total number of arguments, which can be greater than the number of unique elements.

Next, the nested for loops are very inefficient. Your algorithm traverses the array for every element in the array- so it will run in O(n^2) time.

Think: do you have to traverse the array more than once? Why not just use a hashtable (dictionary in C#) to keep track of counts as you traverse the array? A hashtable uses a very efficient lookup mechanism to tell you if you've already seen the element, and the value can be used to keep track of count.

Consider replacing your problematic code with the following, and understanding how it works.

```
        Dictionary<int, int> elementCounts = new Dictionary<int, int>();

        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            int element = array[i];
            if (elementCounts.ContainsKey(element))
                elementCounts[element]++;
            else
                elementCounts.Add(element, 1);
        }


        Console.WriteLine("How many same elements?");
        foreach(KeyValuePair<int,int> count in elementCounts)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Element: {0} Count: {1}", count.Key, count.Value);
        }
```

Then, if you want to copy the results in the hashtable (Dictionary) to a two-dimensional array, you can do the following.

```
        int numberOfUniqueElements = elementCounts.Count;
        int[,] secArray = new int[numberOfUniqueElements, 2];
        int j = 0;
        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, int> count in elementCounts)
        {
            secArray[j, 0] = count.Key;
            secArray[j, 1] = count.Value;
            j++;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use Linq's *GroupBy* to do this

```
var array = new int[] { 2, 1, 2, 2, 5 };
var result = array.GroupBy(x => x).Select(x => new[] { x.Key, x.Count() }).ToArray();
```

Comment: This would be an array of object though right?  Not a 2 dimensional array

Comment: @maccettura no, it initializes an int-array  `new[] {}`

Comment: Exactly, which creates an array of anonymously-typed objects. A 2 dimensional int array is `new int[,]`

Comment: Ah, but that is still not a two dimensional array, its a multi-dimensional array (an array of arrays)

Comment: My bad, you are right, this creates a `'a[][]` (still far from the OP's `int[,]` though

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a hash table. Let the number in the array be the hash entry key, and let the value of the hash entry be the count. Then just iterate through the array once. While iterating through the array check if hash entry exists if so add 1 to it, if not create it.

Something like

```
for(int i = 0; i<n;i++) {
  if(hashTable.containsKey(array[i])) {
    hashTable[array[i]]++];
  } else {
    hashTable.add(array[i],1);
  }
}
```

Please note that this is quedocode and will require to lookup the methods and implement it correctly.